# libreoffice: impress shortcut to resize image to optimal size for slide?

Tags: libreoffice-impress

I've got a whole bunch of slides that are simply an image from a screenshot I took and I want them to be maximized to be as big as the size of each slide. So I would manually add the Picture from file, then go to change the size of the image with "Position and size..." and then go to "Alignment -> Centered" to re-center again. Is there a shortcut to do that in a quicker manner if I have to do it for a whole bunch of them?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're using an older version of libreoffice, I'm using 4.0.2.2, and if I create a blank slide and insert an existing picture (in my case a .png file) into it, it automatically resized itself to the full slide.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are asking for is creating a macro for the actions you listed
and assigning it a keyboard shortcut.

Doing this is described in the [LibreOffice Documentation](http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/documentation/), Chapter 13 - Getting Started with Macros.
This chapter can be downloaded as a [PDF file](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/e/e8/0114GS3-CustomizingLibO.pdf). Use this link so as to not be confused by the mistake in the name
of this Chapter in the Documentation page.